# Drupal 7.40 Upgrading .htaccess, set the X-Content-Type-Options header to "nosniff"

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-7

I have a drupal website and I upgraded it to 7.40 however the new release of Drupal ask to set the X-Content-Type-Options header to "nosniff" in the .htaccess file.

I am not sure, but which .htaccess file should I change the one in the root or the one in the default file. also where should I add the code in the .htaccess file?

```
X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the one in the root folder of drupal, .htaccess files have an effect on all subfolders.